# How to validate a ListBox (MVVM)?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, listbox

i hope I can explain my code and my problem properly, because it´s a lot of code. We´re making a Book Manager Application in Visual Studio. The Model (Book.cs) contains the properties of the book (Author, Title, Release, etc).

In the MainWindow.xaml we have a ListBox with all the books listed and on the left side there are Labels and TextBoxes corresponding the Properties (Label "Author" and in the TextBox appears the Author´s name).  With this textboxes you can update the properties. So does the xaml look so far:

```
<Window x:Class="BookApplication.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:model="clr-namespace:BookApplication.Model"
        xmlns:viewModel="clr-namespace:BookApplication.ViewModel"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Book-Manager" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <model:Book x:Key="myBook" Title="Harry Potter und die Heiligtümer des Todes" Author="J.K.Rowling" Publisher="Carlsen" Edition="1" Release="01.01.2017" ></model:Book>
        <viewModel:BookCollectionViewModel x:Key="bcvm"></viewModel:BookCollectionViewModel>

    </Window.Resources>


    <DockPanel>
        <Menu DockPanel.Dock="Top">
            <MenuItem Header="Datei">
                <MenuItem Header="Neu" Command="{Binding NewClick, Mode=OneWay, Source={StaticResource bcvm}}" InputGestureText="Strg+N"/>
                <Separator/>
                <MenuItem x:Name="Open" Header="Öffnen" Command="{Binding LoadClick, Mode=OneWay, Source={StaticResource bcvm}}" InputGestureText="Strg+O"/>
                <MenuItem x:Name="Save" Header="Speichern" Command="{Binding SaveClick, Mode=OneWay, Source={StaticResource bcvm}}" InputGestureText="Strg+S"/>
                <MenuItem Header="Speichern unter..." Command="{Binding SaveAsClick, Mode=OneWay, Source={StaticResource bcvm}}"/>

            </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Header="Neues Buch" Command="{Binding NewBookClick, Mode=OneWay, Source={StaticResource bcvm}}"></MenuItem>
        </Menu>


        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="252*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="265*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Grid Grid.Column="0" Margin="-2,0,0,0">
                <Label x:Name="labelTitle" Content="Titel" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="9,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="46" Height="20" FontSize="8"/>
                <TextBox x:Name="textboxTitle" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="20" Margin="87,10,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding ElementName= BooksListBox, Path=SelectedItem.Title}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="160" FontSize="8" />

                <Label x:Name="labelAuthor" Content="Autor" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,30,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="62" Height="22" FontSize="8"/>
                <TextBox x:Name="textboxAuthor" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="18" Margin="87,34,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap"  Text="{Binding ElementName=BooksListBox, Path=SelectedItem.Author}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="160" FontSize="8" />

                <Label x:Name="labelPublisher" Content="Verlag" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,52,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="45" FontSize="8" Height="24"/>
                <TextBox x:Name="textboxPublisher" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="17" Margin="87,58,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource myBook}, Path=Publisher, Mode=TwoWay}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="160" FontSize="8" />

                <Label x:Name="labelEdition" Content="Auflage" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,76,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="45" FontSize="8" Height="26"/>
                <TextBox x:Name="textboxEdition" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="15" Margin="87,79,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding ElementName=BooksListBox, Path=SelectedItem.Edition}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="160" FontSize="8" />

                <Label x:Name="labelRelease" Content="Veröffentlichung" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="9,99,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="102" FontSize="8"/>
                <TextBox x:Name="textboxRelease" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="14" Margin="87,103,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding ElementName=BooksListBox, Path=SelectedItem.Release, Mode=TwoWay}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="160" FontSize="8" />

                <Label x:Name="labelISBN" Content="ISBN" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="9,120,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="81" FontSize="8"/>
                <TextBox x:Name="textboxISBN" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="14" Margin="87,125,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding ElementName=BooksListBox, Path=SelectedItem.Isbn}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="160" FontSize="8" />

                <Button x:Name="buttonRemove" Command="{Binding RemoveBookClick, Mode=OneWay, Source={StaticResource bcvm}}" Content="Löschen" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="9,160,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
            </Grid>

            <ListBox Grid.Column="1" x:Name="BooksListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource bcvm}}" SelectedItem="{Binding Source={StaticResource bcvm}, Path=SelectedBook}">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="12" Text="{Binding Path=Title}"/>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Author}"></TextBlock>
                                <TextBlock Text=";  Auflage: "></TextBlock>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Edition}"></TextBlock>
                            </StackPanel>
                            <Canvas Width="50" Height="12" HorizontalAlignment="Left" >
                                <Ellipse Name="LeftEllipse" Height="10" Stroke="Black" Fill="{Binding Path=ColorLeft}" Width="10" Canvas.Left="10"/>
                                <Ellipse Name="MiddleEllipse" Height="10" Stroke="Black" Fill="{Binding Path=ColorMiddle}" Width="10" Canvas.Left="30"/>
                                <Ellipse Name="RightEllipse" Height="10" Stroke="Black" Fill="{Binding Path=ColorRight}" Width="10" Canvas.Left="50"/>
                            </Canvas>
                        </StackPanel>

                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>

            </ListBox>

        </Grid>
    </DockPanel>

</Window>
```

If you click on any book on the list, the values of the Properties will be in the left TextBoxes, and these you can edit, as I said.

Now I have to do the validation. The problem is, I could only find like direct validation of the properties, and I want to validate the values and updated values of the ListBox.

I´ve tried to do something like this (source : https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms753962, the source isn´t in english, but the code is pretty clear).

I made a class AuthorRule that looks like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace BookApplication.Model.Validation
{
    class AuthorRule : ValidationRule
    {
        public AuthorRule()
        {

        }

        public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, CultureInfo cultureInfo)
        {

           if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace((String)value))
           {
                return new ValidationResult(false, "Dieser Feld ist verpflichtend.");
            }
            else
            {
                return new ValidationResult(true, null);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

just to proof, if the Field is empty. My Model or Book.cs hasn´t been changed. 
My MainWindow.xaml looks like this (it´s like the other piece of code, but I will just show the changes in WindowResources and in the TextBox "Author"):

```
<Window.Resources>
        <model:Book x:Key="myBook" Title="Harry Potter und die Heiligtümer des Todes" Author="J.K.Rowling" Publisher="Carlsen" Edition="1" Release="01.01.2017" ></model:Book>
        <viewModel:BookCollectionViewModel x:Key="bcvm"></viewModel:BookCollectionViewModel>

        <ControlTemplate x:Key="validationTemplate">
            <DockPanel>
                <TextBlock Foreground="Red" FontSize="20">
                    <Run Text="!" />
                </TextBlock>
            </DockPanel>
        </ControlTemplate>

        <Style x:Key="textBoxInError" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding (Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent, RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self}}" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>

        </Style>

    </Window.Resources>
```

[image]

The image above is a screenshot of the TextBox "Author" .I don´t know what the path and the source should be, so that the ListBox ist still connected!!

I´m sorry for the long question, can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

You have already set Text property in the first line and you are again setting it back in the node TextBox.Text. You may have to remove the Text attribute and it's value in the  first place.
Also, Source field is not required. End solution for TextBox should be something like this.

```
<TextBox x:Name="textboxAuthor" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="18" Margin="87,34,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="160" FontSize="8" Validation.ErrorTemplate="{StaticResource validationTemplate}" Style="{StaticResource textBoxInError}">
                    <TextBox.Text>
                        <Binding Path="SelectedItem.Author" ElementName="BooksListBox" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
                            <Binding.ValidationRules>
                                <validation:AuthorRule/>
                            </Binding.ValidationRules>
                        </Binding>
                    </TextBox.Text>
                </TextBox>
```

This should work.